# Find non-overlapping subsets that maximize the sum of their values

Tags: optimization, sets

> Given a set of elements $N$, a set $S$ of subsets of $N$, and a function $v:S \to \mathbb R$, determine a set $R\subseteq S$ of *non-overlapping* subsets that maximizes the total value.

Has this problem already been studied somewhere, or is it linked to some well-known optimization problem?

Comment: Is the function $v$ positive valued?

Comment: No, it is not positive valued.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this problem has already been studied. It is a well-known $NP$-complete problem known as [Set-Packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_packing). Your problem is a [weighted optimization variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_packing#Weighted_version), but the same principles apply.

Comment: I see. Basically set packing is a special case of this problem, with $v(\cdot)=1$ for all subsets.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce it to the following graph theoretic problem, but I don't know if it is in $P$.

Denote each set in $S$ as a vertex and give it a weight $f(S)$, in other words your vertices are weighted. Then if two sets are overlapping connect them by and edge. Then you have to find a subset $V'$ of vertices such that if $v,u \in V'$ then $(u,v) \notin E$, that is they are not adjacent to each other and sum of weights of vertices in $V'$ have to be maximal.

**UPDATE**:
According to ryan's post it is NP-complete.